# Pass an array to a deposit method in Vyper

Tags: solidity, vyper

I'm trying to create a deposit function in Vyper that I can pass an array of addresses and amounts to eg:

```
{
  "beneficiaries": [
    {
      "address": "0x7066047ae211c46A284C8b3042819ED06B3148A5",
      "amount": "100"
    },
    {
      "address": "0x5076047ae211c46A284C8b3042819ED06B3148A7",
      "amount": "50"
    },
    {
      "address": "0x3096047ae211c46A284C8b3042819ED06B3148A9",
      "amount": "75"
    }
  ]
}
```

The deposit function would then parse through the array and send the specified amount of ERC20 token to each address.

Whilst I can do the parsing of the array and the sending, I'm very much stuck on how to pass the array as an argument to the method as an argument.

Any help appreciated thank you